# Multiple service providers to establish link

Tags: phone

If data roaming is disabled, could service providers still use links from multiple service providers to establish connections between a carrier and a destination point?

Comment: Could you expand on this question? I'm having trouble being certain exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: Telstra does not have network connections to Brazil. If Telstra is my ISP, is there a possibility my phone call could go across the following networks:

Me --> Telstra --> Optus --> My friend in Brazil

Comment: I want to make sure my service provider is always Telstra and doesn't switch at any point due to the lack of service in the area.